# Convert with JS a Solidity bytes32 to a Solidity string

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development, string, bytes32

I have functions which are forced to return a `bytes32` object, but then in my webapp I need to reconvert them to a classic `string`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using the web3.js function `web3.toAscii` [(doc)](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii), which might [change name](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/363) to web3.toUtf8 or something similar in the future.

Comment: I see at the top of the documentation that these features are not yet released. Are these features still not released or is the documentation out of date?

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.0 of web3 js use the new utils function

`web3.utils.hexToAscii('0x4920686176652031303021')`

[doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii)